# CGContextDrawPath for two inner and outer Rect of different colors

Tags: ios, cgcontext, quartz-2d, uigraphicscontext

I am using the below code in drawRect

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGMutablePathRef outerPath=[self createPath:rect];

CGMutablePathRef innnerPath=[self createPath:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];

CGPathCloseSubpath(outerPath);

CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:38.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor);

CGContextEOFillPath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

CGContextAddPath(context, innnerPath);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:213.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.4].CGColor);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

But, since I am using 0.4 alpha for the inner colour , the inner colour becomes brown.

How can I have something like this as show in below?

[image]

Comment: There is no image “show in below”.  Please edit your question to include an image or a link to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make a single rectangle, fill it with a cyan color, and stroke it with a red color. Make sure you set the stroke width to the size you need.

Comment: Thats a nice solution. But, if I want the glossy effect for the inner rect then what would be the easiest way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What "glossy effect" do you mean?